# Replace text in menu with icon in small screen bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, glyphicons

I can add icons next to texts in the menu but fails to hide text (keep icons only) in small screen.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
     <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
         Home
     </a>
  </li>
  <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
  <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or something or explain better what the expected result is and what the current result is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each menu item (text, without the glyph icon) in a span with a class of hidden-xs. This will hide the text and only leave the icons when the website is viewed on xs devices.

```
<span class="hidden-xs">Home</span>
<span class="hidden-xs">About</span>
<span class="hidden-xs">Contact</span>
```

**[Working demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/fraktar/pen/YVLvYd)**

Resize window to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your text in a div or span or paragraph, like this

```
<p class="hidden-xs">some text </p>
```